# how can I make two encodings be the same?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, type-conversion

I have two text files in two different encodings. A sample image of the content of each file (when doing "cat file" on a Mac) is given below.

I know that these two files contain information in Chinese. I am trying to get the two files to agree on the encoding.

When I use "file -i filename", I get iso-8859-1 for the second image and utf-8 for the first one. Then, I try using

```
  iconv -f iso_8859-1 -t utf-8
```

(this one does not change the file)

or

```
  iconv -f utf-8 -t iso_8859-1
```

(this one gives a "cannot convert" error while scanning the file, the first time it hits a Chinese character in the first image).

Neither of these commands work.

Any ideas how to normalize these two text files so that they have the same encoding?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does OSX keep track of the encoding, or is it guessing?  Seems like the latter.

Comment: I actually don't know. I tried this on a Linux machine, though. The OSX part was just catting the file to grab an image.

Comment: If it's on a Linux machine, then the encoding is almost certainly a guess.  Do you have any idea what the actual encoding is -- as in, the encoding specified by who/whatever created the file?  Without that, basically all you have is a bunch of bytes.

Comment: I tried to look for that information, but I couldn't find it...

Comment: If it's Chinese, then the chances of the actual encoding being Latin-1 are slim to none.  You'll want to try various Chinese encodings, like GBK and Big5, assuming that the file isn't already in UTF-8 or UTF-16 and `file` isn't just confused.